# Why loop and array stops working after adding innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, innerhtml

Everything works fine except inner `HTML`. I get the name from the parent but as soon as I add `innerHTMl` in the code it doesn't work. I want to get `innerHTML` from every parent in the loop,array ..., I don't know why it doesn't work, where am I wrong?

Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll('*'));
  var divsname = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("parent"));
  var divshtml = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("parent")).querySelectorAll('*').innerHTML;
  // Loop over the array
  var results = "";
  var name = "";
  divsname.forEach(function(div) {
    name += div.getAttribute("name");
    var innerhtml = "";
    divs.forEach(function(div) {
      innerhtml += divshtml;
    });
    results = "<br> Div element" + name + "have innerHTML" + innerhtml + ".";

  });

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="parent" name="parentone">
    <div id="childone" style="height:10px">
      <div id="childtwo" style="background-color:red"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent" name="parenttwo">
    <div id="childthree" style="height:10px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Kindly guide me for this issue.

Thank You

Comment: `results = "<br> Div element" + name + "have innerHTML" + innerhtml +`, this is a syntax error due to the trailing arithmetic operator. Everything will stop when the browser reads this line. Are you sure you read the browser console log?

Comment: I mistyped it from my computer, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try it out:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll('*'));
  var divsname = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("parent"));
  
  var temp = document.querySelectorAll("*");
  var divshtml = Array.prototype.slice.call(temp).innerHTML;
  // Loop over the array
  var results = "";
  var name = "";
  divsname.forEach(function(div){
    name += div.getAttribute("name");
  var innerhtml = "";
  divs.forEach(function(div){
    innerhtml += divshtml;
  });
    results = "<br> Div element" + name + "have innerHTML" + innerhtml;

  });

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results ; 
}
```

`querySelectorAll` is a method on DOM elements that accepts a CSS selector and returns a static NodeList of matching elements.

`Array.prototype.slice.call` is one way to turn that NodeList (which acts like an array, but doesn’t have the methods from Array.prototype) into a real array.

Comment: I need to get innerHTML from each class = parent individually. If add: var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("wp-activ").querySelectorAll("*"); not working!

Answer (score 0):

because `document.getElementByClassName` is not a function, u should try with id

```
  var divshtml = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("parent").querySelectorAll('*'));
```

in the HTML:

```
  <div id="parent" name="parenttwo" >
```

Comment: It should only be with class, not with id, any idea some other possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

By class you can do like this it will give you all inner node elements between this class node:

```
let divshtml = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("randerHTML")[0].querySelectorAll('*'));
```

Note: it will return NodeList not the string like innerHTML